# ShareActionProvider does not work when showAsAction=ifRoom

Tags: android, shareactionprovider

I'm creating a small application and tried to provide a Share button on the ActionBar. The relevant code looks as below:

**Manifest**

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

**Menu Item**

```
<item android:id="@+id/shareMenuItem" android:showAsAction="never" android:title="@string/shareAction" android:orderInCategory="100" android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"></item>
```

**Activity**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.shareMenuItem);
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) shareItem.getActionProvider();
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Everything works fine in this scenario. I wanted to show the Share button on the ActionBar and changed showAsAction="ifRoom". The Share button now shows up in the ActionBar, but its not clickable.

I tried to change other menu items to ifRoom, and they are working fine. Don't really understand why Share button alone is not working correctly. Any help/suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason of "non-clickable" shareAction button is missing intent for your `actionProvider` (that is an intent for which Android could find a match). 
Try setting it via

```
mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(youIntentWithAction);
```

before you return from `onCreateOptionsMenu`

**Update**
I believe it works correctly for the case showAsAction="never" only because intent is correctly set by the time you open *overflow* options (those marked with "never") and click you `shareItem` and this does not happen when you have it in the action bar.
One guess is that you set your action intent in implementation of `onPrepareOptionsMenu` (if you have one), which will be only called when you open `overflow` items (+ once during startup) and not for actionBar items.

**one important thing is**: 
`onOptionsItemSelected` is NOT triggered for menuItem with *actionProvider*, if it is shown in the action bar (i.e. *actionProvider* will still trigger `onOptionsItemSelected` on user action if this *actionProvider* is in *overflow* menu).

That might explain why you don't have a chance to dynamically `setShareIntent` for your *actionProvider* when `showAsAction="ifRoom"`.

If you still want `setShareIntent` in `onOptionsItemSelected`, you may need to do it when handling selection of another (non-*actionProvier*) item.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: My Intent depends on user action. So I can't set it in onCreateOptionsMenu. If I set some static value, Share button is enabled. But without doing all this, it works fine when the showAsAction="never". It disables only when showAsAction="ifRoom", which looks strange to me.

Comment: Currently, I'm calling setShareIntent in onOptionsItemSelected method. The content I share is dynamic. If I change it to ifRoom, Share button is disabled. It works when I setShareIntent in the onCreateOptionsMenu as you have suggested. I tried setting with a String member variable and tried to update the variable based on the content. It only takes the first value with which I set the Intent.

Comment: I appended to my answer addressing your last comment. Please check it out

Comment: Cool...It makes sense now. I moved setShareIntent to another method and it works as expected now. Thanks!

Comment: HEY @jobinbasani,  can you explain how did you achieve that ?